# Any good approximations for Stirling numbers?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, stirling-numbers

Are there any good approximations for Stirling numbers which are less computationally intensive? To be a bit more specific, assuming a particular parametrization of the generalized Stirling numbers:

$S(a,b;-1,-d,0)=\frac{1}{b!(-d)^b}\sum^{b}_{j=0}(-1)^{b-j}{b \choose j}\prod_{k=0}^{a-1}(k-jd)$

This is very computationally expensive. I know that we can replace all factorials/gammas using the [Stirling approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), but that only is a good *asymptotic* approximation. Any pointers, ideas, appreciated.

Comment: This could be of interest : http://www.academia.edu/7996039/Asymptotic_Estimates_for_Second_Kind_Generalized_Stirling_Numbers

Comment: Absolutely no idea ! I found this paper after your post came. Good luck. Cheers.

Comment: " I know that we can replace all factorials/gammas using the Stirling approximation, but that only is a good asymptotic approximation". First, to get good asymptotic approximations of the Stirling numbers it's quite more complex than just replacing factorials by the Stirling approximations, because we have an alternating sum - see eg [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/162764/understanding-a-particular-approximation-for-stirlings-number-of-the-second-kin). Second, I think that most approximations of Stirling numbers are indeed asymptotic approximations.